# Does using atlbase.h makes my compiled app to have some extra dependencie?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, atl

I would like to know if including **atlbase.h** in my c++ project will make the compiled application to have a dll dependency or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. The Project Configuration in the IDE has a setting to tell whether your ATL project should link to ATL statically or dynamically. This affects only a small part of ATL though -- most of it is templates, so including the header in your code is all that's needed. There are a few bits and pieces that can/do go in a library though, and the setting will govern whether those come from a DLL or a static library.